# Why does document.execCommand('undo') not work in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I am working on a chrome extension that lets users pre-configure action sequences.

I noticed that document.execCommand('undo') doesn't work in TinyMCE.
However tinyMCE.execCommand('undo') works fine.

Is there a way to make document.execCommand('undo') work directly in TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

Any text or images or other items added to the editor creates an event in the separate, TinyMCE DOM. This is why `document.exeCommand('undo');` won't affect added content and returns 'false' in the console.

To see this in action, I contrasted TinyMCE with a standard `textarea` and `content editable` section, and tried out the commands in the console: the document.execCommand returns 'true' when run in the console for undoing content in the textarea and contenteditable. But it does return 'false' for TinyMCE.

(As for a way to make document.execCommand run in TinyMCE, I'm not sure it is possible.)